# Why is my Host Path Persistent Volume reachable from all pods?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage, persistent-volume-claims

I'm pretty stuck with this learning step of Kubernetes named `PV` and `PVC`.
What I'm trying to do here is understand how to handle shared read-write volume on multiple pods.
What I understood here is that a `PVC` cannot be shared between pods unless a NFS-like storage class has been configured.
I'm still with my `hostPath` Storage Class and I tried the following (**Docker Desktop** and **3 nodes microK8s cluster**) :

1. This `PVC` with dynamic Host Path provisionning

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-desktop
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
```

2. Deployment with 3 replicated pods writing on the same `PVC`.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: library/busybox:stable
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args:
            ["-c", 'while true; do echo "1: $(hostname)" >> /root/index.html; sleep 2; done;',]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /root
              name: vol-desktop
      volumes:
        - name: vol-desktop
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-desktop
```

3. Nginx server for serving volume content

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:stable
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
              name: vol-desktop
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: vol-desktop
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-desktop
```

Following what I understood on the documentation, this could not be possible, but in reality everything run pretty smoothly and my Nginx server displayed the up to date `index.html` file pretty well.
It actually worked on a single-node cluster and multi-node cluster.

What am I not getting here? Why this thing works?
Is every pod mounting is own host path volume on start?
How can a hostPath storage works between multiple nodes?

EDIT: For the multi-node case, a network folder has been created between the same storage path of each machine this is why everything has been replicated successfully. I didn't understand that the same host path is created on each node with that `PVC` mounted.
To anyone with the same problem: each node mounting this hostpath `PVC` will have is own folder created at the `PV` path.
So without network replication between nodes, **only pods of the same node will share the same folder**.
This is why it's discouraged on a multi-node cluster due to the unpredictable location of a pod on the cluster.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, `RWO` means "one or many RW from single node" not single pod. so as long as all the pods are in same node, they would be able to access the data

Comment: [Documentation on access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

Comment: Alright @P...., but after further tests, this setup also works on a multi-node cluster. Thanks for your help

Comment: in your "multi-node" cluster, how's your pod located ? are they scheduled on single node or multi-node. try `kubectl get pod -owide` to see there nodes.

Comment: For the tests, there were 15 pods replicated on 3 nodes :   
- Node 1: 5 pods   
- Node 2: 5 pods    
- Node 3: 5 pods

Comment: @P.... a server setting was replicating same folder path on each node, at the time I did not understand the way a hostPath works this is why things were blurry. It is clear now, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to handle shared read-write volume on multiple pods.

Redesign your application to avoid it.  It tends to be fragile and difficult to manage multiple writers safely; you depend on both your application correctly performing things like file locking, the underlying shared filesystem implementation handling things properly, and the system being tolerant of any sort of network hiccup that might happen.

The example you give is something that frequently appears in Docker Compose setups: have an application with a mix of backend code and static files, and then try to publish the static files *at runtime* through a volume to a reverse proxy.  Instead, you can build an image that copies the static files *at build time*:

```sh
FROM nginx
ARG app_version=latest
COPY --from=my/app:${app_version} /app/static /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Have your CI system build this and push it immediately after the backend image is built.  The resulting image serves the corresponding static files, but doesn't require a shared volume or any manual management of the volume contents.

For other types of content, consider storing data in a database, or use an object-storage service that maintains its own backing store and can handle the concurrency considerations.  Then most of your pods can be totally stateless, and you can manage the data separately (maybe even outside Kubernetes).

> How can a hostPath storage works between multiple nodes?

It doesn't.  It's an instruction to Kubernetes, on whichever node the pod happens to be scheduled on, to mount that host directory into the container.  There's no management of any sort of the directory content; if two pods get scheduled on the same node, they'll share the directory, and if not, they won't; and if your pod's Deployment is updated and the pod is deleted and recreated somewhere else, it might not be the same node and might not have the same data.

With some very specific exceptions you shouldn't use `hostPath` volumes at all.  The exceptions are things like log collectors run as DaemonSets, where there is exactly one pod on *every* node and you're interested in picking up the host-directory content that is different on each node.

In your specific setup either you're getting lucky with where the data producers and consumers are getting colocated, or there's something about your MicroK8s setup that's causing the host directories to be shared.  It is not in general reliable storage.

Comment: Thanks for you detailled answer and your time !

Comment: I think this can really help Kubernetes learners though the architecture of apps.
For MicroK8s, with my misunderstanding of hostPath and some server settings, is it normal that things works, i edited my question.

Comment: How to deal with multi-pods folder share then ?
Real use-case : My PHP app needs session folder sharing for multiple replicas. This is not something I can change and I need to deal with that. Is folder sharing the inevitable ?

Comment: It sounds like that setup can't usefully run more than 1 replica in Kubernetes.  (How would you have deployed the application on multiple nodes before there were containers?)  Can you store the session data in a database, or in the session cookie itself (it's usually pretty small)?

Comment: Interesting questions!
I was targeting rolling updates and high availability, just for training purpose!
Unfortunately the app only works with session files and it was a nice way to get how to achieve this in Kubernetes.
Thanks for this conclusion @david-maze !